# fibonacci in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program which finds the sum of even numbers below 4 million the Fibonacci sequence. I know there is a much simpler way of doing this, but I wanted to see if it would work with arrays. I have never really used arrays before as I am fairly new to Java, which is why I wanted to see if this worked with arrays. The main problem that I have is with the for statement. How would I see if the contents of fibarray[i] is less than 4000000?

Also, is it OK if I do the thing with the `fibarray = new int[i]`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] fibarray;
        int numcount = 0;
        int i = 0;
        long sum = 0;
        fibarray = new int[i];
        fibarray[0] = 0;
        fibarray[1] = 1;

        for(i = 0 , fibarray[i] < 4000000, i++;;){
            fibarray[i] = fibarray[i - 1] + fibarray[i - 2];


        }
    }
```

I apologise if this sounds really stupid. 
Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: What do you mean when trying to get an index of Class Name? First of all you have to create an object, let's say `ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>()` or `int[] a = new int[capacity]`. Afterward there is no problem to use such construction as you mentioned `if (a[i] > 4000)`.

Comment: @Bashalex No need to mention ArrayLists. They have different syntax and the OP's fundamental problem is about array syntax.

Comment: Can you provide details/references to support your belief that "it wouldn't work"?

Comment: It wouldn't work because it has syntax error and it uses an array of size 0. Are you trying to sum only the ***even*** Fibonacci numbers up to a sum of 4M ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See comments within the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    /*************************
    * comments on your code
    int[] fibarray; //use right java naming convention
    int numCount = 0; //this variable is never used
    int i = 0;
    long sum = 0;
    fibarray = new int[i];//you initialize an array of size 0.
    fibarray[0] = 0; //you can't set value to array of size 0
    fibarray[1] = 1; //you can't set value to array of size 0

    //wrong syntax
    for(i = 0 , fibarray[i] < 4000000, i++;;){
    //use for(i = 0 ; fibarray[i] < 4000000; i++){

        fibarray[i] = fibarray[i - 1] + fibarray[i - 2];
    }

    *******************************/
    //Alternative code
    //you don't need to keep all Fibonachi numbers found.
    //you only use 3 numbers for every calculation
    int size = 3;
    int totalLimit = 4000000;
    int[] fibArray = new int[size];
    fibArray[0] = 0;  fibArray[1] = 1;
    int total = 0;

    while( true ) {

        fibArray[2] = fibArray[0] + fibArray[1] ;

        if((fibArray[2]%2) ==0) { //even number

            if((total + fibArray[2]) >= totalLimit) {
                break;
            }

            total += fibArray[2];
        }

        fibArray[0] = fibArray[1] ;
        fibArray[1] = fibArray[2] ;
    }

    System.out.println("Total "+  total );  
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications as needed.

Comment: I have the problems that you have put in the comments quite a lot. I've seen what I've done wrong now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'll follow that in the future. Another thing I'd like to ask is, how  would I compare the contents of array[x] to a number? Could I use the > and < symbols to compare the contents of an array to a number?

Comment: Yes. It is simple enough to run a simple test and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I just asked because it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I didn't down vote. I can't - I have less than 15 reputaution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to start your for loop with i = 2. And the for loop should be in this syntax

```
for(i = 2; fibarray[i] < 4000000; i++) {
  fibarray[i] = fibarray[i - 1] + fibarray[i - 2];
}
```

Comment: How do you set the size of fibarray ?

Comment: @c0der you set it with int[] fibarray = new int[size_of_array];